# Using njit with sympy.Piecewise lambdified functions

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numba

I would like to create a SymPy piecewise function defined on a specific part of the complex plane, then lambdify and @njit it.

```
import sympy as smp
from numba import njit

x = smp.symbols('x')
f,g = smp.symbols('f,g', cls=smp.Function)
f=f(x)
g=g(x)
g=smp.sin(x)
f = smp.Piecewise((0,smp.re(x)>2*smp.pi), (0,smp.re(x)<0),(g,True))
```

Thus, I want the function to be sin(x) if x is in [0,2pi], and zero otherwise.

Lambdifying it, things still work:

```
f_num = smp.lambdify(x,f)
f_num(1+2j)
```

but njit() does not, as it has issues with numpy.select and reduce introduced by Piecewise():

```
f_num_njit = njit(f_num)
f_num_njit(1+2j)


TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'reduce' of type Function(<ufunc 'logical_or'>)

File "<lambdifygenerated-128>", line 2:
...
File "<lambdifygenerated-128>", line 2:
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return select([logical_or.reduce((less(real(x), 0),greater(real(x), 2*pi))),True], [0,sin(x)], default=nan)
    ^
```

Interestingly, issues with njit and select/reduce can sometimes be avoided by not using numpy, if `f` was a real function I could use `smp.lambdify(x,f, modules='math')` and this would work fine as lambdify() wouldn't use select/reduce. Unfortunately, 'math' module doesn't support complex numbers (duh), and sympy doesn't support 'cmath'. Thus, we're at an impasse.

You can somewhat force it to work by using `modules=[{'re':np.real,'sin':np.sin},'math']` but I'm not sure I want to lose out on potentially more efficient numpy implementations just to avoid lambdify() using a single unsupported function.

I'm not sure if this is a XY problem, I'd like to find a way to make f_num_njit work since **g(x) is actually a much more computationally expensive function**, but there might be a better way to do this overall - perhaps completely avoiding Piecewise(). I just want f to have a specific form on an interval and have no contribution otherwise.

Edit:

1. This is possible to do, as demonstrated in MWE and comments above. I'm looking for a way to avoid issues with numba and numpy without a hacky workaround that loses most of numpy's functionality.
2. This is a MWE, actual definitions of g(x) and similar functions are in tens to hundreds lines of code if written manually. Yes, I could write this on paper and implement it by hand, I have, but I'd like to see if I can avoid that using sympy for everything up to the last step.

Comment: You cannot njit functions using sympy. This is not possible. Numba is not a general JIT : it only support mainly Numpy function and standard Python built-ins. In fact, not all Numpy functions are supported. This is mentioned in the beginning of the Numba doc. Please read it. If you want a general JIT, then PyPy is the way to go, but PyPy does not support all packages.

Comment: In your question you've stated *I want the function to be sin(x) if x is in [0,2pi], and zero otherwise* Do you need `sympy` for that? You can create normal function and use `numba` jit on that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'm sorry, you might have misread my question. `You cannot njit functions using sympy` you can, you just have to use lambdify to turn it into a regular python function first. This is entirely possible, it just has issues in this particular scenario. I even provide a workaround for this scenario, I just don't like it because it's hacky and loses numpy because one function has poor support.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I've provided a MWE demonstrating what the problem is. As mentioned in the question, `g(x) is actually a much more computationally expensive function`. Yes, I can and have done that - in practice that's a very large amount of tedious and error prone writing in my case since the function *isn't actually sin(x)*. I would like to move some of my code into SymPy, and I would also like to maintain the speed I need when actually doing numerics on equations.

Comment: @DDADDA You've made it work it with `modules=[{'re':np.real,'sin':np.sin},'math']` and that's ok. `numba` uses `numpy` only for arrays, it doesn't use any numpy functionality - `numba` is compiler that compiles the python script to native code. `numba` just knows what `np.array` is and knows how to access the memory in the array.

Comment: @AndrejKesely It would seem that numba has limited support for select+reduce (https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html). Do you know of any way to stop Sympy from using those without losing other numpy functionality? It's perfectly capable of returning a lambdified function that uses if-else (which works in numba) to check for domain in this particular scenario when you disable numpy (as in my workaround).

Comment: You can read the python code that `lambdify` produced from the error message (or `help(f_num)`, and then write you own `njit` friendly version.  It would be ok to use a loop and `if/else` instead of the `select`, since `njit` will compile it.  `lambdify` is basically a crude translator from sympy to python/numpy/math, without any deep understanding of the differences.  You can use that as a start and bring your own knowledge/experience to play.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, that's certainly an option, but at that point it's easier for me to derive long equations on paper and just type them in manually. I've done this, it's tedious and error prone, which is why I'd love to be able to do the symbolic work in sympy and then *efficiently* evaluate it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you don't want to use `math` module, but `numba` doesn't like `np.logical_or.reduce`.

You can then define your own `logical_or.reduce`:

```py
from functools import reduce


@njit
def my_logical_or_reduce(arr):
    return reduce(np.logical_or, arr)


f = njit(
    smp.lambdify(
        x,
        f,
        modules=[
            {"logical_or.reduce": my_logical_or_reduce, "re": np.real, "sin": np.sin}
        ],
    )
)

a = 1 + 2j
print(f(a))
```

Prints:

```
(3.165778513216168+1.9596010414216063j)
```

Comment: `If I understand you right, you don't want to use math module`, yes, I'd like to be able to use numpy, but avoid using numba unsupported numpy functions like select and reduce. Re:answer, this is a great idea and a good starting point. Adding "numpy" to modules, but replacing select/reduce is something that might be feasible. This still throws an error after including "numpy", but overall this seems like a good direction to explore.